# My website is accessible on my home network but nobody else can access it on the internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, port-forwarding

I have set up my Ubuntu server and have my site working on my home network, I am able to see my website on all devices connected to my router but beyond that nobody else can see it.
I have a Belkin (F9J1002 v1) router which I have set up port forwarding to my server's IP.
To rule out any port issues with my ISP I have called them and they said that they DO allow port 80 traffic. To be certain I forwarded port 80 to my laptop and used a program called PFPortChecker which determined that I do have access to port 80.

My website should be located at 192.168.2.11 I have associated it with the domain www.shekko4444.com

Comment: Hello shekko.. I'm curious to know how you assigned the domain name "www.shekko4444.com" and do you have a static IP assigned from your ISP? I've myself tried things similar to what you've done here, but with no success, and I think it's something in port-forwarding that I'm missing.. I've heard you could port-forward with dynamic IP too (which is what I have), is that right? And, I know there are a lot of pages there which guides just what I'm asking right now from you, but could you please summarize the process esp. focussing on the IP stuffs in this post or other self-answered AU post.

Comment: Hi rusty, starting with the domain name I used godaddy.com to purchase the domain name, once bought in the settings of the domain I pointed it to my PUBLIC IP address, not the 192.168.*.* which is the private IP address as I learnt from others on here.
I have a static IP which I configured on my server since you have the option to change it from static to dynamic. 
The process which I went though for port forwarding was to first make sure that my server was listening to port 80, which it was by default. Then to make sure my router was forwarding port 80 to my servers IP. Hope I was of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the public address of your router.  192.168.2.1 is an internal IP address used in home networking - it also happens to be the address of the router right next to me, and I suspect the address of several million routers across the world.

You are looking for the address that your ISP assigns to your router.  If your comfortable with your routers configuration program, you could use that.  Otherwise, you could call your ISP.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! You and another person are right, I was confused of which IP to use and it works fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
$ host www.shekko4444.com  
www.shekko4444.com is an alias for shekko4444.com.  
shekko4444.com has address 139.216.210.103  
shekko4444.com mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.  
shekko4444.com mail is handled by 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

The `IP` address of your router is `139.216.210.103`. The router should be the only system that knows about `192.168.2.11`, and should forward port 80 there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate your website with your public IP and not `192.168.2.11` 191.168.X.X is a private IP space and would not be routed across the internet

Comment: Check your router for you public IP or if you don't go through proxy you can see it at www.whatismyipaddress.com